# Importing TIFF to SAGA

Tags: geotiff-tiff, saga

I'm trying to import a large GeoTIFF (~1.2 GB) into SAGA GIS for processing as a grid using Import/Export - GDAL/OGR -> GDAL: Import Raster, but it keeps crashing. I'm using the 32bit OSGEO4W SAGA installation, on Windows 7.

[image]

This is the only error message I can see before the GUI freezes, it seems to be a problem with memory.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can change memory allocation settings in SAGA to avoid this crash? I'm sure the station I'm working on has sufficient memory as I can view this raster fine in QGIS and ArcMap. And I'm sure SAGA is working fine as it imports smaller rasters no trouble.

**UPDATE**
I have since installed 64 bit SAGA GIS and this imports the raster no problems. I found [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/354013/thread/8dd1aaf4/) resource on the SAGA forums, explains the memory limitations nicely.

Comment: If you have Windows7 64 bit, you could try Saga 64 bit.